# Why is the first scroll of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS reversed?

Tags: scrolling

The first scroll of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS desktop is reversed after some scrolling inactivity.

It's giving me a headache when I scroll in my code editor, it goes in a nonsensical direction.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking. I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Pilot6 let's say I went afk for a minute, then I use scroll or mouse wheel, the first scroll/wheel goes to a reversed direction.

Comment: Does it happen in all programs? Does it happen only with a specific mouse?

Comment: @Pilot6 usually happens in vscode